# csvsimple command csvreader changes national letter å to a

Tags: csvsimple

I have just began to use the csvsimple package, where I noticed a problem with national letters. The problems occurs with the danish letter `å` (`\aa`) and `Å` (`\AA`). Before the table these letters are written normally, but after the `\csvreader` command. Where it actually changes both the letter and the macroes into `a` and `A` instead. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

I have the following csv file,

```
Navn,c,h,r,s
4.2 A,775,693,1.12,1.42
4.2 B,883,756,1.17,1.49
4.3 B,415,768,0.541,0.688
4.3 C,479,656,0.730,0.929
4.3 D,615,712,0.864,1.10
4.3 E,594,781,0.760,0.967
5.1 A,589,763,0.772,0.982
5.1 B,610,762,0.800,1.02
5.3 A,641,762,0.841,1.07
5.3 B,593,751,0.789,1.00
Navn,4.2,4.3,5.1,5.3
s,1.45,0.921,1.00,1.04
```

I use the following code,

```
\documentclass[danish,12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csvsimple,booktabs}

\begin{document}
æøå ÆØÅ \aa\AA
\begin{table}[H]
     \centering
     \csvreader[head to column names,tabular=|l|l|l|l|l|,%
                table head=\hline Navn & c & h & r & s\\\hline]%
               {Forsoeg/Tabel/ResultatTabel.csv}{}%
               {\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcoliv&\csvcolv}
     \caption{æøå ÆØÅ \aa\AA}
     \label{tab:results}
\end{table} 
æøå ÆØÅ \aa\AA
\end{document}
```

Which generate the following

[image]

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A short extract from the `csv` file is needed to play with.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I completely forgot about adding the csv file. I have added it now

Comment: I can confirm the problem. It seems to be related to `head to column names`, the problem goes away if the first line in the CSV is written differently. No idea what that option is suppose to do.

Comment: @daleif this seems to have solved the problem

Comment: @SimonJensen It is a rather strange thing, try changing the first line to A,B,C,D,E, then it also goes away. Hehe, and if you use `AA,BB,CC,DD,EE` then `\AA` disapears, LOL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens with `head to column names` is that `csvsimple` defines control sequences based on the contents of the first line in the `.csv` file. In particular, it defines `\r` (besides `\Navn`, `\c`, `\h` and `\s`) and does a *global* definition. `:-(`

Thus `\r` gets redefined multiple times and at the end it expands to nothing. Thus `\aa` and `\AA`, whose definition is `\r{a}` and `\r{A}` respectively, turn out to give just ‘a’ and ‘A’ respectively.

The idea behind this is to being able to refer to the current contents of the line as `\Navn`, `\c`, `\h`, `\r` and `\s`, for example with

```
\Navn & \c & \h & \r & \s
```

instead of

```
\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcoliv&\csvcolv
```

However, this must apparently be avoided unless one ensures the column names don't conflict with existing macros.

Removing `head to column names` avoids the issue.

---

The problem is here:

```
\def\set@csv@autohead{%
  \toks0=\expandafter{\csname\csv@current@col\endcsname}%
  \toks1=\expandafter{\csname csvcol\romannumeral\c@csvcol\endcsname}%
  \edef\csv@temp{\noexpand\gdef\the\toks0{\the\toks1}\noexpand\csv@AtEndLoop{\noexpand\gdef\the\toks0{}}}%
  \csv@temp%
}
```

(lines 184–189 in `csvsimple.sty`); the `\gdef` is the problem.

The package should at least warn that a column name could conflict with an existing macro; better, it should keep a list of the redefined macros and restore their definitions after the action of `\csvreader` ends.

Comment: Even then you'd still get into trouble if the second line of the CSV contained `\aa`. An interface like `\Header{Navn}`, \Header{c}` would probably have been better.

Comment: @daleif Definitely better.