# csvloop bug with the word "long"?

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I'm experimenting some issues with the csvloop using the package `csvsimple`. I need help determining if it's a bug with the package, or something I can fix myself.

The word "long" is showing up in my compiled document when it shouldn't, just because it is written somewhere in the excel document. It should not be written at all!

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%Packages

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}   
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvloop{file={tryingwithlong.csv}, head to column names, full filter=\ifcsvstrcmp{\csvcolii}{unidentified}{\csvfilterreject}{\csvfilteraccept}, command=\shotgun,
        before reading={\ },
        late after line={{,}\ }, late after last line=\ .} \\ 

\end{document}
```

[image: this is the excel file]
[image: this is the compiled pdf]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something of this kind has already appeared in [csvsimple command csvreader changes national letter å to a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370534/), but this is worse!

The `head to column names` *globally* (re)defines macros (without notice) from the column names, in this case `\fghj`, `\shotgun` and `\long`.

Unfortunately, `\long` is a TeX primitive and redefining it will lead to every possible disaster.

Don't use `head to column names` unless you're 100% sure the names won't conflict with anything already defined. You can refer to the columns with `\csvcoli`, `\csvcolii` and so on.

Comment: interesting feature

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Quite. More fun if a column is named `box` or `fi`.

Comment: `end` is even more fun.